# How can I see what firebase account is currently logged in using the CLI?

Tags: firebase-cli

Using the firebase CLI how can I see what firebase account is currently logged in? I looked at the command list but I can't find a command for it. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just run `firebase login`. If you are already logged in, it will reply: `Already logged in as user@domain.com`.